# How to remove the year in the date?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have an issue about a Birthdate field since it gave the month, date and also the year. However, I want to remove the year because I don't want to show it out to everyone. How can I do that ?
Moreover, I'm using LWC to create a lightning datatable which show users'birthday of this month, and I don't know how to sort the birthdate ascending because it's stuck with the year, therefore whoever born first will be in the top and so on, it doesn't care about the date. How can I fix that ?
Hope to hear your suggestions !

Comment: When you say whoever is born first , you mean irrespective of the year?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to format the birthdate in apex to just return the day as an Integer in the response alongwith other column data. The integer can then just be shown as a column which can be sorted. The table header can show the current month.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate field with just date and month and sort it in the component. Use a workflow to fill the value in the field.

Answer (score 0):

My approach should be:

1. Create a trigger (or a process builder) to set the Year = 1700 (or any other year) for all birthdate;
2. Create a formula field (As string) to display the Day + Month in the format that I need.